# Blockchain wallet send api not working

Tags: php, node.js, bitcoin, blockchain

I am trying to send the btc by using blockchain wallet.

Check Balance, create address all are working fine.
But when i am trying to send the btc to address.
It gives me the error below:-

```
{"error":"Unexpected error, please try again"}
```

This is what i am calling for sending btc:-

```
http://localhost:3000/merchant/myguid/sendmany?password=pass1&recipients={%22163atph2FLG2WLHfY3fp4sdvsdvdsvds%22:586581}
```

Comment: do you have enough coin to send?

Comment: Yes, i have the coins in my wallet.

Comment: Are you synced with the network?

Comment: what do you mean by synced here?

Comment: it means, is your local copy of the chain up to date?

Comment: i am using the blockchain apis and there is no local copy of chains.